# Why did this weird object appear in blender, and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: mesh, objects, layers

I am new to Blender and I'm following the Blender Guru's donut tutorial. I made it all the way to part 10, when this bizarre object appeared. It seems like it is somehow attatched to my icing layer, but only on the donuts with the long sprinkles. When I delete the object, it deletes the frosting and sprinkles off of my donuts. I deleted the donuts with the long sprinkles and created them again to see if it would fix it, but it did not. If anyone has any advice or wants to check my blend file to see what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it.[image][image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your icing.003 has a Geometry Nodes Modifier that instances the Collection "Long" (which contains many cylinders, or sprinkles, I assume, and one errant cube). Long story short - delete the cube from the "Long" collection.

[image: Long]